# Username and password validation in android

Tags: android

I am trying to validate username and password before logging in to my application with the value stored in database.

This is my database method.

```
public boolean GetData2(String uname, String pass) {
    boolean result;
    Cursor c1 = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MIS2 + "";
    SQLiteDatabase dbc = this.getReadableDatabase();
    c1 = dbc.rawQuery(query, null);
    String u = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_USERID));
    String p = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_PWD));

    if ((uname.equals(u))&&(pass.equals(p))) {
        result = true;

    } else {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
```

This is my condition to check.

```
boolean res = dbh.GetData2(s1, s2);
if(res == true) {
    Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);                      
} 
else {                  
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: and your question is ?

Comment: Are you sure your intent is correctly created ? I think `Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);` should be `Intent in=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);` ? Because you want to go to the MainActivity after the LoginActivity (I assume here that LoginActivity is the first activity showed in the screen)

Comment: and where is `c1.moveToFirst()` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things... first, you're not calling c1.moveToFirst().  Second, unless you only have 1 user, you will most likely never get the result you're looking for because you're only trying to look at the first record returned.

Something better might be:

```
public boolean GetData2(String uname, String pass)
{
    SQLiteDatabase dbc = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c1 =  dbc.query(
            TABLE_MIS2,
            null,
            DatabaseHandler.KEY_USERID  + "=? AND " + DatabaseHandler.KEY_PWD + "=?",
            new String[] { uname, pass },
            null,
            null,
            null);
    return (c1.getCount() >= 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for helping me.. I just added c1.moveToFirst() alone in my db method. Problem solved.. Thanks again..